# Unrecognized selector sent to instance when adding observer to PDFView

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit, notificationcenter

I'm trying to do some UI changes when a user swipes to the next or previous page in the PDFView. I have it set up to use the default PageViewController. I'm adding an observer onto the PDFView and I have a selector set up for it. It crashes when I try swiping and the error message is this:

```
-[PDFView handlePageChangedWithNotification:] unrecognized selector sent to instance
...
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PDFView handlePageChangedWithNotification:]: unrecognized selector to instance.
```

I've checked for a delegate method and didn't find anything that would help do this functionality. So, I'm assuming I have to have it named properly for this to work. Here is the code that I am using to add the observer:

```
// Add observer to pdfView
// This is added in viewDidAppear()
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(pdfView, selector #selector(handlePageChange(view:)), name: .PDFViewPageChanged, object: nil)

// Selector method for observer
@objc private func handlePageChange(view: PDFView)
{
     // Do some changes
}
```

I expect to be able to check when a new page is shown to be able to check the PDFOutline if this page is marked as a bookmark and change the bookmark button to show that it is already a bookmark. Thanks for any help you can give.

EDIT: I checked the documentation for the PDFViewPageChanged notification and it says that the notification object is the PDFView itself. It's still crashing tho but I guess that's one issue down. I changed it in the code example above to what I have now.

Comment: You don't have somewhere in your code `handlePageChanged` instead of `handlePageChange`?

Comment: I changed it to `handlePageChanged` and it still crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're telling notification center to notify the `PDFView` when the notification triggers. `PDFView` doesn't implement that method. Whatever class you wrote the method in is what should be handling the notification. So:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector #selector(handlePageChange(view:)), name: .PDFViewPageChanged, object: nil)
```

Also, your notification handler method has the wrong signature. Notification center passes the notification to the method, not the actual view, so you would want it to be

```
@objc private func handlePageChange(notification: Notification)
```

Comment: Haha thank you! I actually figured this out right as I saw you answered it. Idk why all the solutions I found had me setting it to the pdfView. Thanks a bunch!